# A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Network Controller.exe

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("C:\\Part1.txt");
    int n = 0;
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line != ""){
            if (n > 8){
                cout << line.substr(line.length() - (line.length()-27l)) << '\n';
            }
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }

    myfile.close();
}
```

I'm getting the error of:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Network Controller.exe
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

What can I do?

Comment: First, you probably should re-create your project as a Win32 project, instead of a C++/CLI application.

Comment: So what happens when one of the lines (past the first 8) is shorter than 27 characters?

Comment: Put the break point and find out the position where your are getting this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading comment from @Sebastian Redl, ^, i think this will solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    int n = 0;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line != ""){
            if (n > 8){
                if (line.length() > 27)
                    cout << line.substr(line.length() - (line.length() - 27l)) << '\n';
            }
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }

    myfile.close();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will probably avoid the crash, but whether it solves the underlying problem is a different question.

Comment: he has not provided an explanation of desired output, all the explanation provided says that there is crash in some part of code snippet ;)